# ffmpeg преобразовать непроигрываемый фрагмент файла видео, в проигрываемый фрагмент?

Tags: c++, node.js, видео, ffmpeg

С помощью API браузера произвожу захват видео (html5 .webm) и отправку фрагментов на удаленный сервер. С кодеками особо не знаком, но получается что первый фрагмент проигрывается а последующие уже нет. Я так понимаю в чанке не хватает каких то заголовков. 
- Можно ли на стороне сервера, используя ffmpeg произвести упаковку сегмента так чтобы он стал полноценным видео файлом (и проигрывался)?
- Будет ли эта операция менее затратной по сравнению с операцией транскодирования файла в flv и последующей отправкой его на rtmp?

Comment: а как происходит разбивание на фрагменты? просто сколько не жалко читаем и пишем в файл? тогда просто на сервере нужно дописывать в файл и все.

Comment: Существует метод ```mediaRecorder.ondataavailable``` он возвращает данные из [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob) и очищает его. После этого мы берем этот фрагмент и отправляем на удаленный сервер любым видом транспорта. На сервере эти фрагменты (грубо) получают расширение webm и пишутся на диск, параллельно добавляясь в index.m3u8 (по аналогии с hls и dash). Но как уже было сказано при таком подходе, первый кусок проигрывается,  а последующие нет. Вот я и думаю, может можно как то на сервере пропустить фрагмент через ffmpeg и сделать из него полноценный webm видео файл?

Comment: Вам не нужен ffmpeg. просто конкатенируйте файлы (или дописывайте в один файл).

Comment: Смысл как раз в том, чтобы не конкатенировать а проигрывать через index.m3u8 как полноценные фрагменты. Возможно стоит из первого куска выцепить хеадеры? И дописывать их в начало последующих файлов?

Comment: вытянуть хедеры можно. Но вот только обычно формат видео файлов "достаточно сложный, что бы просто так делить на куски и цеплять хедеры". А вот один большой файл легко порезать на мелкие куски `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 8 -f segment output%03d.mp4`